# Facing problem while using map function in react

Tags: javascript

have a React component. It loads a local JSON file. In the constructor I want to loop through the local JSON file, find an item that matches a URL parameter, and set some state values. Here is my code so far:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";

import topics from './topics.json';

class Tutorial extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    topics.map((topic, index) => {

      if(topic.url === this.props.match.params.url)
      {
        this.state = {
          url: this.props.match.params.url,
          name: topic.name
        };
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Tutorial">

        <div className="ca-nav-spacer w3-hide-small"></div>

          {this.state.name}
          {this.state.url}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tutorial;
```

I keep getting this error: Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function.

Must the map function return a value? If I'm not returning a value should I just use a for loop? Can I return the block of JSON and then set the state after the map? What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: You are not returning anything within the `.map()` function. If you want to loop through the entries use `.forEach()` instead.

Comment: Use `.forEach` instead of `.map`

Answer (score 1):

`Array#map` should be used to create a new array based on applying a given function to each element. If you just want to loop, this is an inappropriate use of `map` and `Array#forEach` should be preferred instead.

However, in this case, there is a more specific array function for this purpose: `Array#find`.

```js
const topic = topics.find(topic => topic.url === this.props.match.params.url);
if (topic)
    this.state = {url: this.props.match.params.url, name: topic.name};
```

Comment: I still maintain this should be closed as a dupe, but you gave the OP a better way so +1